# Force sending a transaction using ethers

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

I am using ethers js and want to send a transaction forcefully that might result in an error. Metamask allows me to do so, and so does remix, by hitting 'force send' - but when I do a contract call in my ethers code through a JSON RPC, it gives me an error saying 'transaction reverted: '

How can I force send a transaction programatically?

Comment: The "transaction reverted" is most likely the result of the force-sent transaction (that reverted  though). Can you give a link to the reverted transaction on a blockchain explorer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, `overrides` object with preset param `gasLimit` should be passed as last parameter. See more at [ethers docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend)

Reference to ethers library maintainer comment [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/903#issuecomment-648398488)

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I was able to do this by overriding gas limit and gas price.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30309453)